# in a javascript object, what's best way to get the attribute of a value?

Tags: javascript, object, attributes

if we have a javascript object

```
var calories = { apple:200, pear:280, banana:300, peach:325 }
```

what is best way to find the (first) fruit that has 280 calories?

could `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(calories).forEach...` but there should be a better way.

For example, I was thinking of `Array.prototype.indexOf()` which does the same thing for an Array.

Comment: Do you want the first with _exactly_ 280 calories or _at least_ 280 calories?

Comment: @nnnnnn - a simple reverse lookup

Comment: Cool. Regrettably there's no built-in equivalent to `.indexOf()`, though obviously it's simple enough to create a short function to do it. A `for..in` loop is my recommendation for the moment just because it is supported by older browsers.

Comment: @nnnnnn - coming to same conclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear search using `for..in` construct:

```
var fruit = null;

for (var prop in calories) {

  if (calories[prop] == 280) {

    fruit = prop;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `hasOwnProperty()` to filter `prop` in your loop - pretty much what `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` does for you

Comment: The code is based on your example `calories` object definition, and thus `hasOwnProperty()` check is not necessary in this case.

Comment: If you wanted to put this in a function for ease of use in multiple places in your code you could have a function parameter to control whether to use `.hasOwnProperty()` or not.

Answer (score 2):

Caution! There is no guarantee that all browsers return the same result. In fact they don't.

For example:

```
var x = { a: 1, b: 1 };
delete x.a;
x.a = 1;
```

What should `x.indexOf(1)` return here? `b` or `a`? Turns out IE does property enumeration differently than other browsers, and the specs say that's perfectly fine. So IE would return `a` while other browsers would return `b`.

You can verify that by calling

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x); // IE: a,b - other browsers: b,a
Object.keys(x); // same
for (var i in x) { console.log(i); } // same
```

Obviously, the problem here is that there's no notion of "order" on object indices because, well, that's what objects are: unordered maps.

Comment: really good points.  explains why no built-in backwards search mechanism.

Comment: Turns out that `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` might even use a different sorting than `Object.keys()`. So after all, the spec is a bit messy there, and some sort of `Object.prototype.indexOf()`  wouldn't make things worse.

Answer (score 1):

> but there should be a better way

No, there really shouldn't. The way 99% of all use cases go, developers are more interested in getting the value from the key.

Comment: although I respect your opinion I beg to differ.  for example, Array has indexOf(), doing the same thing, and in an Array 99% of the time one is interested in getting the value by index.  developers (of which I have been for more than 35 years) are frequently interested in symmetric properties.

Comment: One-dimensional mapping and two-dimensional mapping are different concepts. The javascript's object represents an one-dimensional mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the prototype of Object doing this:

```
// Returns one key (any) of the value if it exists, or undefined if not
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "keyOf", { 
    value: function(value) {
        for (var key in this) if (this[key] == value) return key;
        return undefined;
    }
});
```

Using this way instead of the common `Object.prototype.keyOf = ...` will work with jQuery if you use it.

And then you could use it like this:

```
var myArray = {...};
var index = myArray.keyOf(value);
```

It will also work with normal arrays: `[...]`, so you could use it instead of `indexOf` too.

Remember to use the triple-character operators to check if it's undefined:

```
index === undefined // to check the value/index exists    
index !== undefined // to check the value/index does not exist
```

Of course you could change the name of the function if you prefer and remember not to declare any variable called 'undefined'.

Remember also that as indexOf, it will return at most one key defined but it could be more than one possible, so in that case you will need something like this (`.keysOf(...)`):

```
// Returns all the keys of the value if it exists (an empty array if not)
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "keysOf", { 
    value: function(value) {
        var allKeys = [];
        for (var key in this) if (this[key] == value) allKeys.push(key);
        return allKeys;
    }
});
```