# javascript: how to get index of an object in an associative array?

Tags: javascript

```
var associativeArray = [];

associativeArray['key1'] = 'value1';
associativeArray['key2'] = 'value2';
associativeArray['key3'] = 'value3';
associativeArray['key4'] = 'value4';
associativeArray['key5'] = 'value5';

var key = null;
for(key in associativeArray)
{
    console.log("associativeArray[" + key + "]: " +  associativeArray[key]);        
}

key = 'key3';

var obj = associativeArray[key];        

// gives index = -1 in both cases why?
var index = associativeArray.indexOf(obj); 
// var index = associativeArray.indexOf(key);  

console.log("obj: " + obj + ", index: " + index);
```

---

The above program prints index: -1, why? Is there any better way to get index of an object in an associative array without using loops?

What if I want to delete 'key3' from this array? the splice function takes first parameter as index which must be an integer.

Comment: There is no associative array in javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in a javascript object, what's best way to get the attribute of a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052888/in-a-javascript-object-whats-best-way-to-get-the-attribute-of-a-value)

Comment: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`indexOf` only works with pure Javascript arrays, i.e. those with integer indexes. Your "array" is actually an object and should be declared as such

```
var associativeArray = {}
```

There's no built-in indexOf for objects, but it's easy to write.

```
var associativeArray = {}

associativeArray['key1'] = 'value1';
associativeArray['key2'] = 'value2';
associativeArray['key3'] = 'value3';
associativeArray['key4'] = 'value4';
associativeArray['key5'] = 'value5';

var value = 'value3';
for(var key in associativeArray)
{
    if(associativeArray[key]==value)
         console.log(key);
}
```

Without loops (assuming a modern browser):

```
foundKeys = Object.keys(associativeArray).filter(function(key) {
    return associativeArray[key] == value;
})
```

returns an array of keys that contain the given value.

Comment: What if I want to delete 'key3' from this array? the splice function takes first parameter as index which must be an integer.

Comment: @gmuhammad The `splice()` method only operates on arrays, not objects. You will need to remove the property using `delete associativeArray['key3']`, for example.

Comment: thg435: You probably caused a bit of confusion by using the word 'array' in your variable name. Perhaps `associativeMap` might have been better to make clear it is an object, not an array?

Comment: @thg435, and GregL: Thank you very much both of you, GregL, you are right, I was confused and want this array to be treated as traditional array. But now I am clear. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use jQuery, you could extend the prototype of Object doing this:

```
// Returns the index of the value if it exists, or undefined if not
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "associativeIndexOf", { 
    value: function(value) {
        for (var key in this) if (this[key] == value) return key;
        return undefined;
    }
});
```

Using this way instead of the common `Object.prototype.associativeIndexOf = ...` will work with jQuery if you use it.

And then you could use it like this:

```
var myArray = {...};
var index = myArray.associativeIndexOf(value);
```

It will also work with normal arrays: `[...]`, so you could use it instead of `indexOf` too.

Remember to use the triple-character operators to check if it's undefined:

```
index === undefined // to check the value/index exists    
index !== undefined // to check the value/index does not exist
```

Of course you could change the name of the function if you prefer to for example `keyOf`, and remember not to declare any variable called 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

```
let elementIndex = -1;

array.forEach((element, index, array) => {
   if (element["key"] == "someValue") {
      elementIndex = index;
   }
});
```

TypeScript Style:

```
let elementIndex = -1;

this.array.forEach((element, index, array) => {
   if (element.key. == "someValue") {
      elementIndex = index;
   }
});
```