# How to get index of an array element which has more than one sub elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I am working in javascript and I would like to find the index of an element in an array .

```
var task = [{taskno:'1',todo:'cooking'},{taskno:'2',todo:'play'}];
```

now i want to find the index of task which has todo as cooking and i dont know its task no .... is there any inbuilt function ?

I have tried this code but It's not working:

```
  var index = task.indexOf(todo:'cooking');
```

Now I'm using a for loop is there any other way?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: as far as i know `there's no built-in indexOf for objects`. Check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273157/javascript-how-to-get-index-of-an-object-in-an-associative-array) as well.

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` will give you the index of an object in an array, but you must already have a reference to that object.

e.g.

```
var o1 = { val: 'o1' },
    o2 = { val: 'o2' };

[o2, o1].indexOf(o1); //1
```

If you do not have a reference to the object, you will have to create your own search algorithm.

```
var tasks = [{taskno:'1',todo:'cooking'}, {taskno:'2',todo:'play'}];

var index = indexOfFirstMatch(tasks, function (task) {
    return task.todo === 'cooking';
});

console.log(index); //0

function indexOfFirstMatch(arr, matcher) {
    var i = 0, len = arr.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (matcher(arr[i])) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the actual object, vs. just it's index. You could use the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library and it's [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) function:

```
var task_wanted = _findWhere(task, {todo: "Cooking"});
```

If you actually need the index, then use task_wanted to search the array with indexOf().